# Navigation component title bar is not getting updated for new destination's label

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

In my app I'm using navigation component

I created the navigation graph and actions and all seems working fine.

My only issue is the toolbar of the app. Its title is not getting updated
based on each destination label. However it only displays the app name.

Navigation

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
    android:name="com.udacity.shoestore.login.LoginFragment"
    android:label="LoginFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_welcomeFragment"
        app:destination="@id/welcomeFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
        app:exitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/fade_in" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/welcomeFragment"
    android:name="com.udacity.shoestore.welcome.WelcomeFragment"
    android:label="WelcomeFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_welcome">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_welcomeFragment_to_instructionFragment"
        app:destination="@id/instructionFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
        app:exitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out"
        app:popEnterAnim="@android:anim/fade_in" />
</fragment>
```

Application tag in Manifest

```
   <application
        android:name=".ShoeApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

Comment: Please include your code where you [set up your app bar with Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#top_app_bar).

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps to set this up I'll break it down as easily as I can and provide notes along the way

Step 1 Create a Toolbar in the MainActivity XML.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    />
```

You can find additional help in setting up Actionbar in the [dev docs](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up)

The rest of the steps will take play in the MainActivity onCreate()
Step 2 set Toolbar

```
setSupporActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))
```

Step 3 create a reference for the navHostFragment
Because the view isn't loaded the fragment view cannot be found. For the navController to be properly set, the fragment view needs to be created and onViewCreated needs to be dispatched, which does not happen until the `activity created` state.

```
val navHostFragment: Fragment? = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

Step 4 Post the call to the findNavController method on a handler and execute all actions needed.

```
val navController = navHostFragment!!.findNavController()
```

Step 5 Combine the action bar with the NavController.
The start destination of your navigation graph is considered the only top-level destination. on all other destinations, the Action bar will show the Up button

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
```

The MainActivity onCreate() should loo like this.

```
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))
        val navHostFragment: Fragment? = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val navController = navHostFragment!!.findNavController()
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
```

Step 6 handle up button

```
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()
    }
```

You can additional details [here on the android dev docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar)